# Pageviewcontroller can't instantiate controller from XIB

Tags: swift, xib, uipageviewcontroller, nib

I have a pageViewController nib with its class pageViewControllerClass. On it I instantiate a myCustomViewController nib with its myCustomViewControllerClass that has outlets.
I use

```
guard let myViewController1 = UINib(nibName: "myCustomViewControllerClass", bundle: Bundle(for: myCustomViewControllerClass.self)).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? myCustomViewControllerClass else { return }
```

I add it to view controller using:

```
setViewControllers([myViewController1], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

While there are not outlets connected from myCustomViewController to myCustomViewController class the nib loads fine, but when an outlet is connected my app crashes saying

> pageViewController this class is not key value coding-compliant for
>   the key myOutletName.

I've tried using bundle as nil, setting instantiate(owner:myCustomClass.self), setting bundle as main. So far it keeps crashing. I would greatly appreciate suggestions on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: check the class name in xib file while selected file owner

Comment: It's set to the correct class.

Comment: and you said its set corrent? if you are setting "myCustomViewControllerClass" as file's owner but than in "guard let myViewController1 = UINib(nibName: "myCustomViewControllerClass", bundle: Bundle(for: myCustomViewControllerClass.self)).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? myCustomViewControllerClass else { return }
" you are setting it to self so its craching

Comment: guard let myViewController1 = UINib(nibName: "myCustomViewControllerClass", bundle: nil) else { return } use this

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, it was the matter of me overthinking the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, I used

```
let myViewController1 = myCustomViewControllerClass()
```

and just passed it to the

```
setViewControllers([myViewController1], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It was a matter of overthinking the solution.